# Inconsistency in HTML rendering for <b> , <i>, <u> tags

Tags: javascript, html, dom, rendering

I have HTML structure saved in database, which gets rendered in my text editor.
It is similar to the following one:

```html
<div>
    <b>
        <u>
            <i>
                This is sample text
            </i>
        </u>
    </b>
</div>
```

I have found this inconsistency that some times above HTML gets rendered as

```html
 <div>
     <u style="font-weight: bold; font-style: italic;" >
          This is sample text
     </u>
</div>
```

This inconsistent behavior affects further code.

I would like to know why DOM gets manipulated with uncertainty and how to avoid this?

Comment: You're looking at default browser styling. Historically they were used in styling content, much like the `center` element, so some browsers still add italics (`i`), bold (`b`), and underline (`u`). --- Although I have no data on which browsers still do this.

Comment: I'm using Chrome V.59

Browser renders it using <tags> only, but sometimes tags gets converted into inline style.

Comment: Wonderful. -- When you say there is "inconsistency", which browsers don't style b/i/u like the above example?

Comment: I pass HTML with <tags>, which gets assigned as innerHTML. 
But instead of processing given input as is, browser converts them to style ellements. I want to know if there is any method to prevent this.

Comment: That's a very different question. Maybe close this one, and ask that one as a new one?

Answer (score 0):

You have third party software messing about with your markup which isn't really great software behaviour, whichever way you look at it.

In order to prevent this occurring I would be tempted to swap:

```
<div>
    <b>
        <u>
            <i>
                This is sample text
            </i>
        </u>
    </b>
</div>
```

for:

**CSS:**

```
.bold {font-weight: bold;}
.underline {text-decoration: underline;}
.italic {font-style: italic;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <span class="bold">
        <span class="underline>
            <span class="italic">
                This is sample text
            </span>
        </span>
    </span>
</div>
```